# how to draw lines between each row in a list?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

The below given is the code which use getting each row of a list,

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="575" Margin="6,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="430" Height="80">
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="90" Width="305">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="Medium" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268" FontSize="25"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="0,36,0,-1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TaxType}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Row="0" Width="125" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percentage}"  FontSize="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Height="75"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Now how can i draw a line at the end of this stack panel(i.e between each row in the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is,Add your current data within the stackpanel and then add **Path** mentioned in the previous answer and place these two within a stackpanel with **Orientation = Horizontal**

Answer (score 0):

In your StackPanel underneath all other, apply this:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Red" />
```